# In a React Component, how to conditionally show a style while iterating over a list

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React component that list out all users and their point rankings. I want to specific which row it the currentUser. See component:

```
const RankingsList = ({rankings, currentUserId}) => {
  return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {rankings.map(r =>
           <li className="list-group-item" key={r.user_id}>
             <p key={ranking.user_id}>{r.display_name} - {r.points}</p>
             <p>!{currentUserId}!</p>
           </li>
        )}
      </ul>
  );
};
```

For each iteration of rankings, I have the r.user_id and the currentUserId. What I would like to do is when the r.user_id == currentUserId apply a class like `active`.

Should I be doing this inline or should this be done in the ranking array on the API or in some area of React like to reducer?

Comment: Pretty sure inline. The API IMO should only supply the means to get the information, and the reducer returns the next state. Unless the current user ID is stored in state (which IMO it shouldn't be), then do it inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it inline, for example:

```
<li
  className={`list-group-item ${r.user_id == currentUserId ? 'active' : ''}`}
  key={r.user_id}
>
```

If you think it's too verbose, you can also extract it in a function

```
<li className={getClassNames(r.user_id)} key={r.user_id}>
```

What's good with React is that's just javascript, so you can do it the way you would without JSX.

Comment: That's even simplier than my solution, I wasn't sure if you could just put the condition directly inside the `${}`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your current `map` by:

```
{rankings.map(r => {
    const active = r.user_id === currentUserId ? 'active' : '';
    return (
       <li className={`list-group-item ${active}`} key={r.user_id}>
         <p key={ranking.user_id}>{r.display_name} - {r.points}</p>
         <p>!{currentUserId}!</p>
       </li>
    })
)}
```